# Change border color for subclassed UIButton in different states

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a custom `UIButton` subclass that I'd like to change the border color depending on if this state is `UIControlStateNormal` vs `UIControlStateDisabled`

Initially in my `awakeFromNib` is where I set all the defaults

```
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Now what I would like is when the state of the button is `UIControlStateDisabled` it has the same border color as the titleColor for that state, so in this case `[UIColor grayColor]`

My initial attempt was overriding `titleForState` like so

```
- (NSString *)titleForState:(UIControlState)state
{
   if (state == UIControlStateDisabled)
   {
     self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   }
   else 
   {
     self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
   }

   return [super titleForState:state];
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: ```-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up your border colour just when you set new title not when you change button state. You should override setEnabled: method so every time you will change the state to disable/enable via this method the border will be change:

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    if (enabled)
    {
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    }
    else
    {
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    }
}
```

Remove your titleForState: method and try this.
Hope this will help.